# Invalid pure specifier c++

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Can anyone tell me why this line produces this error?

```
virtual void Calculate(Pose *out_pose, HiBoneMask *mask = NULL, HiBoneMask *positionMask = NULL) = NULL;
```

I've been trying to compile this demo for a skeletal animation library in both visual studio and code blocks. Visual Studio gives me 194 errors code blocks just the one. I'd rather get code blocks to work so that's why I presented this error. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace `= NULL` at the end with `= 0`

Comment: I just tried that XD and i get 94 errors after that. On to the next

Answer (score 3):

It should be `=0;` for a pure virtual function. `NULL` is not necessarily `0` (for instance it can be `0L`).

Answer (score 1):

The [NULL](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/NULL/) in c++ have a double-meaning:

> NULL: 
>   Null pointer This macro expands to a null pointer constant.
>
> A null pointer is generally used to signify that a pointer does not
>   point to any object. In C++, NULL expands either to 0 or 0L.

So in your case, you should use

`function(arguments) = 0;`

Answer (score 1):

NULL != 0, but you can use #define NULL 0, if you like to use 'NULL'.

Answer (score 0):

NULL != 0.

```
virtual void Calculate(Pose *out_pose, HiBoneMask *mask = NULL, HiBoneMask *positionMask = NULL) = 0;
```

is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring pure virtual function you use

```
 virtual void function() = 0;
```

instead of NULL;

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `= 0` instead of `= NULL` ?